# Помогите задать максимальное значение тега <progress>

Tags: javascript, html5

Как задать максимальное значение тега progress (только HTML 5) через javascript?Заранее благодарю.

```js
function loading(max) {
  var start = 0;
  var progress = document.getElementById('loading');
  var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    progress.value = start;
    start++;
    if (start >= max) {

      start = 0;
    } else {
      progress.value = start;
    }
  }, max);
}
var max = parseInt(prompt('Введите максимальное значение ', 100));
loading.max = max;
loading(max);
```

```html
<progress id="loading" max="100" value="0">Загружено на <span id="value">25</span>%</progress>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `var prmax = document.getElementById('loading'); 
var max = parseInt(prompt('Введите максимальное значение ',100)); 
prmax.setAttribute('max', max);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное .

Comment: Совсем забыл про setAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function loading(max) {
  var start = 0;
  var progress = document.getElementById('loading');
  progress.max = max; //изменение значения атрибута max
  var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    progress.value = start;
    start++;
    if (start >= max) {

      start = 0;
    } else {
      progress.value = start;
    }
  }, max);
}
var max = parseInt(prompt('Введите максимальное значение ', 100));
loading(max);
```

```html
<progress id="loading" max="100" value="0">Загружено на <span id="value">25</span>%</progress>
```